# 'Failed - Network Error' when downloading large files without Content-Length header

Tags: http, browser, download

This error shows up most of the time when I tried to download a file without Content-Length header (browser doesn't show the file size). It happens with my PC, regardless of which browser I am using, but works fine on my laptop. Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us an example of the output. That is, issue a `curl -o test BadUrl` command and give us the output ... but substitute BadUrl with a specific URL that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may not be from your PC. The error may cause by server that has slow upstream. Usually it happen to me when I download from ftp server or file server hosted oversea like china and taiwan. When I download those files, I can't see file size but number will keep increasing until it download completely or download corrupt file. Sometimes, server is behind firewall and firewall has been setup to limit speed to outside.